# custom htmlhelper with validation support

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, html-helper

I'm rockin my own custom HtmlHelper to enable [AutoComplete support on a Select List](http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector).

This is working alright, except I need to be able to support the DataAnnotations in my ViewModel.

Here's my current (working) HtmlHelper (sans validation)

```
    <Extension()>
    Public Function AutoCompleteDropDownList(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, name As String, autoCompleteSelectListItem As List(Of AutoCompleteSelectListItem), htmlAttributes As Object) As MvcHtmlString
        Dim selectBuilder As New TagBuilder("select")
        selectBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", name)
        selectBuilder.MergeAttributes(New RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes))
        selectBuilder.MergeAttribute("autocorrect", "off")
        selectBuilder.MergeAttribute("autocomplete", "off")

        Dim selectListBuilder As New TagBuilder("option")
        selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", "")
        selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected")

        Dim innerHtmlBuilder As New StringBuilder
        innerHtmlBuilder.Append(selectListBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))


        For Each item In autoCompleteSelectListItem
            selectListBuilder = New TagBuilder("option")
            selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value)
            selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("data-alternative-spellings", item.AlternativeSpellings)
            selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("data-relevancy-booster", item.RelevancyBooster)
            selectListBuilder.InnerHtml = item.Label
            innerHtmlBuilder.Append(selectListBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))
        Next

        selectBuilder.InnerHtml = innerHtmlBuilder.ToString()

        Return MvcHtmlString.Create(selectBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))
    End Function
```

How would one rewrite this to support validation? Something like `AutoCompleteDropDownListFor()`

PS: a C# solution is perfectly acceptable, the project I'm working on is in VB, but I don't mind translating.

---

PS: I'm flipping through the source code on [http://aspnet.codeplex.com](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72159#338505) and I can't find any reference to `DropDownListFor`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to download the [source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases) and you will find the implementation of the DropDownListFor helper inside `mvc3-rtm-sources.zip\mvc3-rtm-sources\mvc3\src\SystemWebMvc\Mvc\Html\SelectExtensions.cs`. To enable client side validation you have to emit HTML5 data-* attributes on the drop down. This is done towards the end of the `SelectInternal` method by calling `htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes` method.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function AutoCompleteDropDownList(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, name As String, autoCompleteSelectListItem As List(Of AutoCompleteSelectListItem), htmlAttributes As Object) As MvcHtmlString
    Dim selectBuilder As New TagBuilder("select")
    selectBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", name)
    selectBuilder.MergeAttributes(New RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes))
    selectBuilder.MergeAttribute("autocorrect", "off")
    selectBuilder.MergeAttribute("autocomplete", "off")

    Dim selectListBuilder As New TagBuilder("option")
    selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", "")
    selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected")

    Dim innerHtmlBuilder As New StringBuilder
    innerHtmlBuilder.Append(selectListBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))


    For Each item In autoCompleteSelectListItem
        selectListBuilder = New TagBuilder("option")
        selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value)
        selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("data-alternative-spellings", item.AlternativeSpellings)
        selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("data-relevancy-booster", item.RelevancyBooster)
        selectListBuilder.InnerHtml = item.Label
        innerHtmlBuilder.Append(selectListBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))
    Next

    selectBuilder.InnerHtml = innerHtmlBuilder.ToString()
    selectBuilder.MergeAttributes(helper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name))

    Return MvcHtmlString.Create(selectBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))
End Function
```

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section, here's how a strongly typed version of the helper would look like:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function AutoCompleteDropDownListFor(Of TModel, TProperty)(helper As HtmlHelper(Of TModel), expression As Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TProperty)), autoCompleteSelectListItem As List(Of AutoCompleteSelectListItem), htmlAttributes As Object) As IHtmlString
    Dim name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)
    Dim fullHtmlFieldName As String = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name)

    Dim selectBuilder = New TagBuilder("select")
    selectBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullHtmlFieldName)
    selectBuilder.MergeAttributes(New RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes))
    selectBuilder.MergeAttribute("autocorrect", "off")
    selectBuilder.MergeAttribute("autocomplete", "off")

    Dim selectListBuilder = New TagBuilder("option")
    selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", "")
    selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected")

    Dim innerHtmlBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    innerHtmlBuilder.Append(selectListBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))

    For Each item In autoCompleteSelectListItem
        selectListBuilder = New TagBuilder("option")
        selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value)
        selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("data-alternative-spellings", item.AlternativeSpellings)
        selectListBuilder.MergeAttribute("data-relevancy-booster", item.RelevancyBooster)
        selectListBuilder.InnerHtml = item.Label
        innerHtmlBuilder.Append(selectListBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))
    Next

    selectBuilder.InnerHtml = innerHtmlBuilder.ToString()
    selectBuilder.MergeAttributes(helper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name))

    Return MvcHtmlString.Create(selectBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, would it be smarter to send a model instead of a string? Similar to how you do `TextBoxFor`? If so, what might that look like?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell, yes, it will be much better to use a strongly typed helper `AutoCompleteDropDownListFor` taking a lambda expression instead of a hardcoded magic string. I have updated my answer to illustrate an example.