# How to add a custom attribute for a Drop Down List Item?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I have the below code in MVC, Razor:

```
- @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedEvent,
                                 new SelectList(Model.Events, "Id", "Name"))
```

I'd like to add a new attribute for each option in the select called "description" which should be bound to the Event.Description.

How to achieve this?

I'd like to avoid creating a separate Html Helper. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported by current `DropDownListFor` implementation. There is an overload that takes a `IDictionary<string, Object>` of html attributes, but they are bound to the `select` element, not to its items, as you can verify in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703436(v=vs.118).aspx). I don't think you will be able to do what you need here without implementing a custom helper.

Check out a couple of custom helpers that implement a similar behaviour in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505264/html-dropdownlistfor-with-custom-parameter).