# DropDownListFor with IEnumerable is Nasty, not DRY

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2, dropdownlistfor

Why is this Html Helper code so nasty? I specify the ID to bind to in the linq expression, but have to do it again in the SelectList? Is there a better way to do this but still keep RelationshipTypes as an IEnumerable?

Model:

```
public class ResponderGuestsModel
{
    public List<GuestInfo> Guests { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Business.RelationshipType> RelationshipTypes { get; set; }

        public class GuestInfo
        {
            public int? RelationshipTypeId { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Guests.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Guests[i].RelationshipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.RelationshipTypes, "RelationshipTypeId", "Name", Model.Guests[i].RelationshipTypeId), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

Comment: Must you use the selectedvalue parameter? It may still automatically bind if you leave it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505264/html-dropdownlistfor-with-custom-parameter

Comment: This is a well known limitation of using `DropDownListFor()` in a loop. If you want to avoid creating a new `SelectList` in each iteration, then you need an `EditorTemplate for typeof `GuestInfo` and pass the `SelectList` to it using additional ViewData