# how to custom Html.DropDownListFor suppet set name attributes in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

```
new { id = " dd" name = " myName" }
```

is not on the name attributes override, how can id coding name attributes override

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Customer.CustomerBiaoshi, Html.GetEnumSelectList<TgNetJZ.CustomerBiaoshi>(), "test",new { @class = "form-control custom-select" ,@id="ddd",@name="myName"})
```

I write like this always shows model name Customer.CustomerBiaoshi, I want to show what I set name attributes "myName"

[image]

It should be for me that the edit page can only use dropdownlistfor to bind the drop-down box to select items, so I need to solve the name property Customer.CustomerBiaoshi override and Model corresponds to CustomerBiaoshi

or how to custom dropdownlist htmlstring on mvc core suppet set name attributes [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20460253/6116267)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another version of dropdownlist creator as

```
@Html.DropDownList(string "name", IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, 
                   object htmlAttributes)
```

In your case:

```
@Html.DropDownList("myName", Html.GetEnumSelectList<TgNetJZ.CustomerBiaoshi>(),
                    new { @class = "form-control custom-select", @id = "ddd" }).
```

But your model binding to `Customer.CustomerBiaoshi` will not work, because model binding uses name attribute and you changed the name attribute to `myName`.

Comment: my edit form use dropdownlistfor to bind selection but my Dto Field CustomerBiaoshiI need to set the name and dto correspondence to assignSo I can only solve the name attributes override with dropdownlistfor

Comment: This cannot be marked as answer when it doesn't solve the problem. `DropDownList` is different from `DropDownListFor` in world of model binding.