# Show tooltip(or title) message on every dropdown list items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tooltip

I’m using a custom dropdownlist and binding elements dynamically, but here I want to show a tooltip message on every items of dropdown list.

**View Code:**

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Industry,Model.IndustryList, "All", new { @style = "width:258px;", @class = "drpDown" })
```

**Controller code:**

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> IndustryList= EntityModel<T>.Where(m => m.t == “something”).ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = t.Name, Value = t.Value);
```

So let me know is there any way to set title on every option items within select tag.

Comment: try `new { @title = "blah" @style = "width:258px;", @class = "drpDown" }`

Answer (score 2):

No, the standard `Html.DropDownListFor` helper doesn't support setting any attributes on the `<option>` tags except the standard ones (`value` and `selected`). You could write a custom helper to achieve that. You may check [`this example`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938038/29407) as well as [`this one`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8208384/29407).

Answer (score 1):

I would also probably go for Darin's answer, you need a custom drop down list.

A quick (and dirty) alternative might be to loop through manually and create your select list and set the title value on the option.

On your controller, maybe populate a view model as such (I'm just using an anonymous object as an example):

```
var SelectListViewModel = new[] {
            new {
                Text = "One",
                Title = "I'm One Title",
                Value = "1"
            },
            new {
                Text = "Two",
                Title = "I'm Two Title",
                Value = "2"
            }

        };
```

and in your view:

```
<select>
    @foreach (var item in SelectListViewModel)
    {
        <option title="@item.Title" value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Not the cleanest, but hopefully might be helpful for someone.