# cshtml hide overflow in the DropdownList but show when the mouse is hovered over

Tags: razor, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down list in my cshtml view. But some strings are too long to be displayed in a single line. As in the below image:

[image]

I need to to set it so that only a certain number of characters is displayed in the dropdownlist and when the mouse is hovered over the whole string shall be scene, similar to a tool tip text.

```
<div class="span11">
        @Html.DropDownList("specificationList", new SelectList(ViewBag.Specifications, "SpecificationId", "Name", ViewBag.SpecificationId), new { @class = "dropdown-toggle" })
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here consists in the fact that the DropDownListFor helper doesn't allow for setting custom attributes on the `<option>` tag. For your tooltip to work you will need to do have the following markup generated:

```
<select name="specificationId">
    <option value="1" title="some very long description">item 1</option>
    <option value="2" title="some very long description 2">item 2</option>
    <option value="3" title="some very long description 3">item 3</option>
    ...
</select>
```

In order to achieve that you could either write spaghetti code in your view to manually loop through the values of your model (totally non recommended) or write a custom HTML helper that will allow you to output this markup. I have shown an example of such helper on [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936579/fun-with-linq-expressions-in-extension-methods/7938038#7938038). And also [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8208384/29407). You could of course adapt the helper so that if the text of the item is longer than certain number of characters it would generate truncate it.

Answer (score 0):

use css text-overflow: ellipsis